# Conditional statement to change class by id for multiple list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, conditional-statements

I have 2 divs with list items that I'm trying to toggle classes on drop. The code looks like this.

```
<div class="wrapper">                                           
    <div id="togglelinks" class="left-column">
        <ul id="sortable1" class="sortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default"><a href=""><img src="img/icon-music.svg" /></a></li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><a href=""><img src="img/icon-nav.svg" /></a></li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><a href=""><img src="img/icon-seats.svg" /></a></li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><a href=""><img src="img/icon-phone.svg" /></a></li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><a href=""><img src="img/icon-weather.svg" /></a></li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><a href=""><img src="img/icon-email.svg" /></a></li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><a href=""><img src="img/icon-calendar.svg" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="stage" class="right-column">
        <ul id="sortable2" class="sortable">
            <li id="music" class="stagearea"><!-- Content Here --></li>
            <li id="nav" class="stagearea"><!-- Content Here --></li>
            <li id="climate" class="stagearea"><!-- Content Here --></li>
            <li id="phone" class="stagearea"><!-- Content Here --></li>
            <li id="weather" class="stagearea"><!-- Content Here --></li>
            <li id="email" class="stagearea"><!-- Content Here --></li>
           <li id="calendar" class="stagearea"><!-- Content Here --></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to on drop toggle the class from the class "stagearea" to another class that is pulled by a unique id set in the list item. My javascript looks like this.

```
<script>
  if ($("#music").addClass('droppedmusic')) {       
  }
  else if ($("#nav").addClass('droppednav')) {
  }
  else if ($("#climate").addClass('droppedclimate')) {
  } 
  else if ($("#phone").addClass('droppedphone')) {
  }
  else if ($("#weather").addClass('droppedweather')) {
  }
  else if ($("#email").addClass('droppedemail')) {
  }
  else if ($("#calendar").addClass('droppedcalendar')) {
  }
</script>
```

So far I'm able to pull the class for the first list item, but none of the rest. Little help anyone?

Comment: You're targeting by ID, adding a class, then checking if there are **more than one** element in the collection, and as ID's are unique, and jQuery will only ever get the first element with a given ID, there will ***NEVER*** be more than one in those collections.

Comment: For each different id I have classes set that I want to be applied to list items on drop. Each one is a unique size.

Comment: You don't get it, `$("#climate").length` will never be more than at most `1`, as jQuery will **not** get multiple elements with the same ID.

Comment: Ok I just altered my javascript, but am still only getting the first class to pull on drop. I updated what I'm now using above.

Comment: Your `if` statements don't do anything.  You are adding a class as the *condition* of your `if`.  Your first condition returns `true` every time because `$("#music")` is not a "falsey" value. You are simply adding a class to it and then JS says "yep it's there" and falls out of your code.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this below. No ID's needed:

```
<div id="stage" class="right-column">
    <ul id="sortable2" class="sortable">
        <li class="stagearea" data-addclass="droppedmusic"><!-- Content Here --></li>
        <li class="stagearea" data-addclass="droppednav"><!-- Content Here --></li>
        <li class="stagearea" data-addclass="droppedclimate"><!-- Content Here --></li>
        <!--etc -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

With this Jquery:

```
$('#sortable2').on('click','.stagearea', function () {
  var $t=$(this);  //get item that was clicked on
  //read the addclass attribute and add it as a  class
  $t.addClass($t.attr('data-addclass'));
});
```

*Minor Jquery Update*

```
$('#sortable2').on('droppable','.stagearea', function () {
  var $t=$(this);  //On droppable rather than on click.
  //read the addclass attribute and add it as a  class
  $t.addClass($t.attr('data-addclass'));
});
```

Comment: Hmm I get what you're driving at and I love the concept, but it looks like there's nothing pulling into my right-column now. I've completely removed my "if statement" as I see what you were saying in your comment above. As you can probably tell I'm fairly new to this type of coding. It's taking a minute to wrap my head around. At any rate, I appreciate all the help. Once I get a working version of my model I'll post it on Github and JFiddle. I've found a lot of the pieces I've been using to put this together from all over the web, but nothing yet that has all the functionality I need.

Comment: @PatrickM I have to approve the change before it becomes available... which I have now.

Comment: I changed the on click to an on droppable.

Comment: I just added my current code to my JSFiddle here --> http://jsfiddle.net/lukeslytalker/xyg92r6c/3/

Comment: The links on the left side do nothing ( `href=""`).  I guess I don't understand what you are trying to do in the fiddle.... the `droppable` event, formerly the `click` event, is on `sortable2` which is in the right column where there is no content....  if you add this to your css you will see what Im talking about..  `#sortable2 {background-color:red;}`

Comment: The links on the left hand side are just place holders. Currently they don't link to anything. They will in the future, but now I just need them to be items I can drag to the right. When they get to the right column they go from a button to a larger sized animation that can be sorted on the right hand side.

Comment: OK.. Then you are using a library for drag and drop functionality.  What I would do is move the `data-addclass` attribute to the items on the left side, trap the event for dragging/dropping whichever is most appropriate, and read the `data-addclass` attribute and add it to the appropriate are on the right side.  I am not familiar with the drag/drop library so I can't help you with that code.  maybe someone else can post an answer.

Comment: Here's an image that explains what I'm currently tring to do - [Link to image](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BwEd8MuIAAAwb08.png).

Comment: Hmm I'm not having any luck with this code. I'm going back to an id based solution. I don't get anything right now when I drag new items into the right column. I did try moving the "data-addclass" to the left column, but I'm still not getting any response.

Comment: So I'm starting to believe that Drag, Drop, Clone & Sort elements wont play well together. I seem to get so far and then start having issues with the libraries. Anyone have a JSFiddle that has Drag, Drop, Clone & Sort options in one module? Is this even possible?